Hyperparameter tuning data output to table in excel
I did hyperparameter tuning for LSTM model in jupyter notebook, and I want to export the output in excel so it will be in table form, however, using this coding, I only get the last output from hyperparameter tuning. I want all output listed down in excel. How can I get that?
df=DataFrame({'Neurons':[neurons], 'Optimizer':[optimizer], 'Learning Rate':[learning_rate], 'Batch Size':[batch_size], 'MSE':[mse]})
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\Daniee\Desktop\output.xlsx", index=False)

I try using this but in excel, it exports only the last output from jupyter notebook.

how about combine all the df before, it is converted to excel?

It is not  good to export the code directly from the notebook to an Excel file since Jupyter Notebook are commonly interactive. Open a CSV to write it then read it through file.to_csv and then read that CSV using pd.read_csv.
Now transfer your data to an Excel file using path like
csv_file.to_excel(str(os.path.join(os.getcwd() , 'output.xlsx')) , index= False)

Or
You could initialize an empty DataFrame before starting the hyperparameter tuning then append the results of each iteration to this DataFrame and at last export the DataFrame to Excel after all iterations are complete.
import pandas
import os
from pandas import DataFrame

Dframe = DataFrame(columns=['Neurons', 'Optimizer', 'Learning Rate', 'Batch Size', 'MSE'])
for (neurons, optimizer, learning_rate, batch_size, mse) in hyperparameter_tuning:# Assuming it is an iterable consisting tuples
    
    results_df = Dframe.append({
        'Neurons': neurons,
        'Optimizer': optimizer,
        'Learning Rate': learning_rate,
        'Batch Size': batch_size,
        'MSE': mse
    }, ignore_index=True)
##You rest of code about hyperparameter tuning
Dframe.to_excel(str(os.path.join(os.getcwd() ,'output.xlsx')) , index = False)


